# Passing different type of objects to unmanaged function

Tags: c#, c, interop

First: I'm sorry if the title is wrong. I'm not sure how to name my problem.

In my C API I have a function:

```
MYAPI_STATUS SetParam(void *hInst, unsigned long param, void *value);
```

This function accepts different types of pointers depending on `param` type. Like this:

```
SetParam(hInst, 1, (void*)"somevalue");
int x = 55;
SetParam(hInst, 2, &x);
```

I'm just writing a wrapper/binding in C# and I have a problem.

```
[DllImport("myapi", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl]
public static extern uint SetParam(IntPtr hInst, uint paramCode, IntPtr paramValue);
```

What's the best way to replicate behaviour from C? So the function would look like:

```
public static uint SetParam(IntPtr hInst, uint paramCode, ref object paramValue);
```

or possibly:

```
public static uint SetParam(IntPtr hInst, uint paramCode, object paramValue);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by marshalling manually first checking type of `object` if the `object` is `string` then I use `Marshal.StringToHGlobalAnsi` if it's something else then I marshall differently based on what I need.

If someone has any better solution feel free to write :)

Answer (score 0):

The `*` sign in C programming means give parameter **`by reference`**, so this code is not match:

```
public static uint SetParam(IntPtr hInst, uint paramCode, object paramValue);
```

Because it gives parameter **`by value`**.

This code is very similar to what you want:

```
public static uint SetParam(IntPtr hInst, uint paramCode, ref object paramValue);
```

But there is a bit difference. When you using `ref` before a parameter you have to initialize it before sending to the method, but by using `out` you don't have this limitation for passing it. So I think the best possible match will be this code:

```
public static uint SetParam(IntPtr hInst, uint paramCode, out object paramValue);
```

Comment: Yeah that's just the passing, I still have to marshall it no matter which way I use to pass.

Comment: is your problem to pass different type of objects to the method?

Comment: Yes, pass different type of objects to unmanaged function. I changed the title.

Comment: Okay, unfortunately I have no ideas to automate that.